# In Backbone.js how do you handle Ordinal Numbering and changing numbering based on jQuery Sortable in the view?

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my situation. I have a bunch of "Question" model inside a "Questions" collection.

The Question Collection is represented by a SurveyBuilder view.

The Question Model is represented by a QuestionBuilder view.

So basically you have an UL of QuestionBuilder views. The UL has a jQuery sortable attached (so you can reorder the questions). The question is once I'm done reordering I want to update the changed "question_number"s in the models to reflect their position.

The Questions collection has a comparator of 'question_number' so collection should be sorted. Now I just need a way to make their .index() in the UL reflect their question_number. Any ideas?

Another problem is DELETEing a question, I need to update all the question numbers. Right now I handle it using:

```
var deleted_number = question.get('question_number');
var counter = deleted_number;
var questions = this.each(function(question) {
    if (question.get('question_number') > deleted_number) {
        question.set('question_number', question.get('question_number') - 1);
    }
});
if (this.last()) {
    this.questionCounter = this.last().get('question_number') + 1;
} else {
    this.questionCounter = 1;
}
```

But it seems there's got to be a much more straighforward way to do it.

Ideally whenever a remove is called on the collection or the sortstop is called on the UL in the view, it would get the .index() of each QuestionuBuilder view, update it's models's question_number to the .index() + 1, and save().

- My Models,Views, and Collections: https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder/tree/master/app/js/survey-builder
- Screenshot: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5xZcIdpJm0NczNRclhGeHJZQkE/edit

Answer (score 2):

More than one way to do this but I would use Backbone Events. Emit an event either when the user clicks something like done sorting, hasn't sorted in N seconds, or as each sort occurs using a jQuery sortable event such as `sort`. Listen for the event inside `v.SurveyBuilder`.

Then do something like this. Not tested obviously but should get you there relatively easily. *Update*, this should handle your deletions as well becuase it doesn't care what things used to be, only what they are now. Handle the delete then trigger this event. *Update 2*, first examples weren't good; so much for coding in my head. You'll have to modify your views to insert the model's `cid` in a `data-cid` attribute on the `li`. Then you can update the correct model using your collection's `.get` method. I see you've found an answer of your own, as I said there are multiple approaches.

```
v.SurveyBuilder = v.Page.extend({
    template: JST["app/templates/pages/survey-builder.hb"],
    initialize: function() {
        this.eventHub = EventHub;
        this.questions = new c.Questions();
        this.questions.on('add', this.addQuestion, this);

        this.eventHub.on('questions:doneSorting', this.updateIndexes)
    },
    updateIndexes: function(e) {
        var that = this;
        this.$('li').each(function(index) {
            var cid = $(this).attr('data-cid');
            that.questions.get(cid).set('question_number', index);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am  a little confused. v.SurveyBuilder has a collection NOT a model. So I'm assuming this.model.models is actually this.questions Also, wouldn't that just set Every question number to the last index in the UL? The statement in updateIndexes would go through each LI in my UL get it's index, then set EVERY model to that index

Comment: My mistake, I missed the this.questions creation. You can set a views model to a collection which is what I thought you did. I'll update my answer. Anyways, `updateIndexes` will update each model to the appropriate index. Why do you say "EVERY" like its a bad thing? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry was out for lunch. So first of all this.$('li').each spits back DOM elements in "this", not views. So it doesn't have .questions attached. But that's actually an interesting idea...is there a way I can get to the VIEW from the dom element? On another note why does this.$('li') work? is it basically saying this.$el.find('li').

Comment: Updated to add a closure. `that` is now scoped properly. Yes this.$ is shortcut for this el find.

Comment: You could probably store a reference to the view with jQuery data but would not recommend doing that.

Comment: right, wasn't the whole point of backbone to get away from storing data using jQuery.data()? But going back to your point, doesn't your code set EVERY model in that.questions.models to index? Basically you're saying, go through each LI, get it's index. Then go through each question and set it's question_number to that index. So first go around it would set ALL the question numbers to 0. Then, 1, then 2....for each element in this.$('li')

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it!!!

1. Make an array of child views under the parent view (in my example this.qbViews maintains an array of QuestionBuilder views) for the SurveyBuilder view
2. For your collection (in my case this.questions), set the `remove` event using `on` to `updateIndexes`. That means it will run `updateIndexes` every time something is removed from this.questions
3. In your `events` object in the parent view, add a `sortstop` event for your sortable object (in my case `startstop .question-builders`, which is the UL holding the questionBuilder views) to also point to `updateIndexes`
4. In `updateIndexes` do the following:

   ```
   updateIndexes: function(){
       //Go through each of our Views and set the underlying model's question_number to 
       //whatever the index is in the list + 1
       _.each(this.qbViews, function(qbView){
           var index = qbView.$el.index();

           //Only actually `set`s if it changed
           qbView.model.set('question_number', index + 1);
       });
   },
   ```

And there is my full code for SurveyBuilder view:

```
v.SurveyBuilder = v.Page.extend({
    template: JST["app/templates/pages/survey-builder.hb"],
    initialize: function() {
        this.qbViews = []; //will hold all of our QuestionBuilder views

        this.questions = new c.Questions(); //will hold the Questions collection
        this.questions.on('add', this.addQuestion, this); 
        this.questions.on('remove', this.updateIndexes, this); //We need to update Question Numbers
    },
    bindSortable: function() {
        $('.question-builders').sortable({
            items: '>li',
            handle: '.move-question',
            placeholder: 'placeholder span11'
        }); 
    },
    addQuestion: function(question) {
        var view = new v.QuestionBuilder({
            model: question
        });

        //Push it onto the Views array
        this.qbViews.push(view);

        $('.question-builders').append(view.render().el);
        this.bindSortable();
    },
    updateIndexes: function(){
        //Go through each of our Views and set the underlying model's question_number to 
        //whatever the index is in the list + 1
        _.each(this.qbViews, function(qbView){
            var index = qbView.$el.index();

            //Only actually `set`s if it changed
            qbView.model.set('question_number', index + 1);
        });
    },
    events: {
        'click .add-question': function() {
            this.questions.add({});
        },
        //need to update question numbers when we resort
        'sortstop .question-builders': 'updateIndexes'
    } 
});
```

And here is the permalink to my Views file for the full code:
https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder/blob/1bee2f0b8a04006aac10d7ecdf6cb19b29de8c12/app/js/survey-builder/views.js

Comment: Looks like a fine solution. Some performance considerations if you're interested. Each append can cause a document reflow which isn't performant. Instead you can collect all of your rendered views and append them at the same time. Given how lightweight your models are another approach could be to have the view of your collection iterate the models and render them. Only one reflow would be triggered once you insert them into the DOM.

Comment: So I would do it that way when I .fetch() from the server right? But if my user clicks "Add Question" I want it to instantly appear on the page. Also the models might get pretty bulky in the future...Right now technically only the views which are changed will rerender. I also updated the QuestionBuilder view to manually change the value of question_number via jQuery .text().

Comment: Yep that would be the time